# How to correctly create castellations?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, via

The problem: I need to use TSSOP-14 ICs instead of SOIC-14. Have plenty of boards already manufactured and assembled. Deadbug wiring is not an option.

I have not found any available converters so I have decided to design one. On (at) the edge, I need to use "half" VIAs like ESP-xx boards:
[image]

What is the correct way of making them? At the moment I have just cut in the middle of the VIA (in real PCB it will be probably the VCUT only)
[image][image]

Is it the correct way of doing it?

Comment: These are known as castellations.  There are [a few questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=castellations) regarding them on this site.

Comment: I did not know this term. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexHajnal thank you. I have ordered and they work !! Some pictures in the answer.

Comment: The daughterboards look good.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @AlexHajnal the funny part is that no UK PCB house wanted to make 8x6mm boards. Had to go to China

Answer (score 1):

I have just received my tiny boards and they work fine:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The PCB company I use have a minimum castellations drill size of 0.6mm but my vias were smaller than that so I have only asked them to cut vias in the middle. It works fine for me.

Comment: This is not an answer, and will be deleted. If you want it to not be deleted, I recommend you add something about what specifically you did here, even if it was just the way you guessed in the question.

Comment: I know how the SO works (on SO my rep is 30k+). It can be deleted if mods decide so. The answer is not for rep - I am not going to accept it or UV

Comment: Why don't you add an addendum to your answer and include the images there?

Comment: @AlexHajnal IMO it makes the distinction between the problem and the solution.

Comment: Why don't you flesh this answer out a bit then: Describe the method you used (e.g. added some vias at the board) and say what method the board house recommended using.  I'm sure you're not the first to have encountered this and having a well-rounded answer would be useful.

Comment: @AlexHajnal I did - normal small vias cut in the middle. No special castellations

Comment: Did the board house suggest an alternate technique?

Comment: @AlexHajnal no, they simply do not accept castellations with drill sized < 0.6mm. They said - we will do at best. Actually the cut is not perfect but there is still enough copper inside the via to connect both sides. BTW it is only 0.6mm thick PCB

Comment: Whether for reputation or not (which really shouldn't matter), an answer should include the actual answer, I think.

Comment: @Hearth I believe that it is simply a nitpick. Maybe my answer will be useful for someone who will have the same problem as me.